# firebase functions Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Change<DataSnapshot>'

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy firebase functions and I get the error

> src/index.ts(132,31): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Change'. src/index.ts(136,65): error TS2339:
>   Property 'params' does not exist on type 'Change'.
>   src/index.ts(142,18): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on
>   type 'Change'.

my code

```
    module.exports.onUserStatusChanged = functions.database
  .ref('/users/{uid}').onUpdate((event) => {
    // Get the data written to Realtime Database
    const eventStatus = event.data.val();

    // Then use other event data to create a reference to the
    // corresponding Firestore document.
    const userStatusFirestoreRef = firestore.doc(`users/${event.params.uid}`);

    // It is likely that the Realtime Database change that triggered
    // this event has already been overwritten by a fast change in
    // online / offline status, so we'll re-read the current data
    // and compare the timestamps.
    return event.data.ref.once("value").then((statusSnapshot) => {
      return statusSnapshot.val();
    }).then((status) => {
      console.log(status, eventStatus);
      // If the current timestamp for this data is newer than
      // the data that triggered this event, we exit this function.
      if (status.last_changed > eventStatus.last_changed) return;

      // Otherwise, we convert the last_changed field to a Date
      eventStatus.last_changed = new Date(eventStatus.last_changed);

      // ... and write it to Firestore.
      //return userStatusFirestoreRef.set(eventStatus);
      return userStatusFirestoreRef.update(eventStatus);
    });
  });
```

it shows red undeline

```
event.data.val()
event.params.uid
```

Comment: check the answer, also im not sure if you are using cloud firestore. If you are using cloud firestore then you need to be using `exports.onUserStatusChanged = functions.firestore.document('/path').onUpdate((change,context) => {` Also check the firestore section https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#cloud-firestore

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this:

```
module.exports.onUserStatusChanged = functions.database
.ref('/users/{uid}').onUpdate((event) => {
// Get the data written to Realtime Database
const eventStatus = event.data.val();
```

into this:

```
module.exports.onUserStatusChanged = functions.database
.ref('/users/{uid}').onUpdate((change,context) => {
// Get the data written to Realtime Database
const eventStatus = change.after.val();
```

Also change this:

```
event.params.uid
```

into this:

```
context.params.uid
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Cloud functions have been updated and to retrieve data after `onWrite` is triggered, you need to use `change` that has two properties before and after, in this case use `change.after.val()`

Comment: what to change 'event.data'.ref.once(...'?

Comment: check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database the methods and the properties that `after` and `before` have are here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot